# Google map Polyline not displaying and throwing error

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

I have Ionic 3 app and I have updated it to IONIC 4 . So when I compile app with xcode 10 for ios 12 google map polylines are not rendering and throwing error. It was rendering perfectly fine for IONIC 3 and ios 11.3 but after updation it has stopped showing:
My code is :

```
for (const path of dashedlinePaths) {

  const lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 4
  };

  let dashedPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeColor: '#ff883c',
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '20px'
    }]
  });

  dashedPath.setMap(this.googleMap);
}

for (const path of linePaths) {

  let linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff883c',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
  });

  linePath.setMap(this.googleMap);
}
```

And errors are showing something like below:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.lineJoin="round"')
runTask — polyfills.js:3880
invokeTask — polyfills.js:4017
n — polyfills.js:3457
runTask — polyfills.js:3880
```

Also its showing warnings like :

```
Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (224 MB).lW — poly.js:52:321
```

Also when I try to zoom map getting the error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.scale')
runTask — polyfills.js:3880
invokeTask — polyfills.js:4017
n — polyfills.js:3457
runTask — polyfills.js:3880
```

Comment: Why downvoted , provide reason, this is not accepted at all

Comment: Am seeing the same problem with Google Maps javascript. I get both the TypeError and the Total Canvas Memory error after I've zoom in and and out for a while.

Comment: Yeah , so do you find any solution for this?

Comment: Still investigating. I want to pass on that there was a problem in web based systems as well as compiling code for native use in IOS. Another insight as I look at this is I only see this when in Safari in IOS. In desktop Chrome, I can pan and zoom around forever with no problems. In IOS Safari, after about 6 to 10 pan and zoom operations with Google Maps I see the errors in the console. Desktop Safari does not have a problem.  Desktop Firefox also seems to be unaffected. So my focus in on IOS Safari.

Comment: ...And on an old iPad (IOS 9.3.5) there are no problems, but on the newer iPad and iPhone with IOS 12 there are problems. This is all on a web based systems that uses styling with Google Maps.

Comment: yes, happened same with my application. Let me know when you get any workaround for this

Comment: Spent the weekend making a simple web page that shows the problem. Submitted reports to both Apple and Google. The page lets you pan and zoom with no icons while watching the "canvas" tab in the apple debugger. You can then tap an button to show icons, pan and zoom, no problems. Then tap a button to add a single polyline, and you will then see 41 orphaned canvases. Reload, press a different button and put down a polygon. More orphaned canvases. Can't share, the test page has too many links into my server. But it's now very easy for both groups to see the break and the javascript behind it.

Comment: @eepete Thanks for the update. I am also investigating this issue and hope will figure out

Comment: Update on Desktop Safari on MacBook Pro with latest versions: It does have a problem and has growing canvases/memory size. It's just it has to get up into the >1.2G-ish size before you get a "This app is using a lot of memory" warning. Might be most users will never see it, as most web sites don't get to run/be displayed for a day or two. As such, users would never be aware of the bug.
My older, can't be updated 2009 MacPro safari doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @PoojaShah Have you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @SachinKumaram I have optimized my code and reduced the occurrence, so sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. but still its facing issue. Still didn't get any specific solution to fix this

Comment: The memory leak goes very fast when a Safari Web Inspector is connected to the page

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Google Maps JS SDK on iOS Safari.

It has been acknowledged by Google, here are two tickets created for this, one even contains a Fiddle explaining how to reproduce it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119875119

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115289894